# Is there a way to dynamically modify a text with Shopify Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a question related to Shopify Liquid Coding, and I'm hoping that you can help me out a little bit!

Basically, I want to have a text dynamically update when a customer increments the quantity of a product on the cart page, without the page restarting. ( Kind of, like, how the price updates on the cart page when someone increases the quantity of a product, without the page restarting.)

This is what I've done so far:

```
<div class="cart__footer">
        {% if cart.item_count == 1 %}
        <p class="grid__item text-right small--text-center">Add another item for 5% discount!</p>
        {% elsif cart.item_count == 2 %}
        <p class="grid__item text-right small--text-center">Add another item for 10% discount!</p>
        {% elsif cart.item_count == 3 %}
        <p class="grid__item text-right small--text-center">Add another item for 15% discount!</p>
        {% elsif cart.item_count >= 4 %}
        <p class="grid__item text-right small--text-center">Hooray! Maximum discount reached!</p>
        {% endif %}
</div>
```

And this actually works, but only if I refresh the page.

What do you think? And ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [Cart JS API](https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart)

I would use the `POST /cart/add.js` method to add an item to the cart. The return value for that endpoint is a JSON object containing the current cart items, eg:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 794864229,
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then read that information and update the page with the correct content using Javascript, eg:

```
let el = document.querySelector('.grid__item.text-right');

if(qty == 3){
  el.innerHTML = "Add another item for 15% discount!"
}
```